# Install Windows XP on a removable hard drive

Tags: windows-xp, installation, boot, external-hard-drive

I've got a hard drive connected to my PC with eSATA. I'd like to install Windows XP on it without having to reboot the computer.

What is the best/easiest/quickest way of doing this?

I plan on inserting the hard drive into an other PC later on.

Comment: You will need to use a Pre-Install Kit that OEM vendors have when they buy Windows Packs. The installation has to continue on the target PC.. but you can use Windows Installation Scripts to automate settings, and post install software.. Not a small job though.. takes some time to perfect it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The install will require a reboot.

Moving it to a new PC will also create issues with hardware incompatibility and driver stability.

Can you provide more info on what you wish to accomplish beyond getting XP installed on the eSATA drive?

Given the cost of a CD/DVD (or the time to "borrow" one from a working system) getting a working CD/DVD is a much better option

Comment: I wish to reinstall Windows on an old computer with a broken cdrom, so, I've disconnected the hard drive and plugged it into hdd communicator. I want to install on it windows XP without it polluting the boot space (e g adding itself to the boot options)

Comment: @ArsenZahray - As Dave points out.  What you want to do will cause a lot of problem, you WILL NOT be able to use the installation, on any either computer.  The first thing you need to do is replace the optical drive

Comment: I hoped to avoid that. ugh....

Answer (score 2):

Extract a `.wim` file to the disk. This will probably take about 15-20 min. or longer depending on the transfer rates for the HDD and CD/DVD. I know Windows 7 DVDs have an `install.wim` that uses the default settings. Windows XP does not, but if you have a wim file that you created with ImageX, that would probably be the most convenient way to set it up. However, you will have to reboot after it is done extracting the files, but at least you can continue to work during the copying/extracting files part.

If you do not already have a wim file, you will have to create one (you can set up a VM, run sysprep, and create the wim file). Unfortunately this will not save time unless you have to install it multiple times.

You can also go into Device Manager and select `Action > Scan for hardware changes`, but you may have to reboot a couple of times. Running `sysprep` with the generalize option will clear hardware-specific settings and drivers, but may cause problems with activation.

Comment: XP does not use wim files for install.

Comment: @Moab - XP can be installed from a wim file, if you have one. It may not be included on the installation disk though.

Comment: "may not", its definitely not on any legitimate XP install disc

Comment: I don't have an XP install disk anymore. I just remember that Windows 2000 and later can be installed from a wim file.

Comment: wim was invented for Vista, did not exist before then....http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format

Comment: True, but the article does mention that "it works equally well with older versions of Windows". A Microsoft [TechNet Library article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722145(WS.10).aspx) says "Although ImageX cannot mount an image from a computer running any other operating system, it can capture and apply images for any version of Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows 2000 Professional."

Comment: you are mixing apples with oranges now. your answer said nothing about using imagex, maybe you should revise your answer. "I'm not sure it Windows XP does or not" Its real clear it does not.

Comment: @Moab I have updated my answer with correct information.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[VMware](http://www.vmware.com/)** for installing the Operating System.

So that it can be movable easily.

**[VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/)**
The Easiest Way to Run a Virtual Machine

Comment: How exactly would that work? The OP wants to boot from the drive later on.

Comment: On VMware settings, we can change the drive letter accordingly. So it should not create any problem while using across PC.

Comment: Can you describe how to do that? I'm quite familiar with VMware, but how exactly do you have to install it?

Comment: ok I will do that

Comment: It can work if you isntall vmPlayer and boot the Vm in the VMPLAyer.. you see

Comment: @ppumkin Where would you install VMware Player? The OP never said they wanted to run a virtual machine, but use the hard drive in another PC. How does this have anything to do with installing the OS on another hard drive?

Comment: I believe the user wants to run it directly, not through a VM. This takes away a lot of performance.